# i am not able to generate xpath of html element through java code or java script

Tags: java, xpath

How to Generate xpath using java code not using any tool or firebug? some one help me to write a java code for my task. see generally we copy xpath from firebug  add-one. but i want to generate xpath when we enter some data in textbox.

Comment: Look man you have to do your homework of your own!!!

Comment: Welcome, see [ask] on how to post questions on the site. You need at least to show some real effort on your side, and post the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getXPath( element )
{
    var xpath = '';
    for ( ; element && element.nodeType == 1; element = element.parentNode )
    {
        var id = $(element.parentNode).children(element.tagName).index(element) + 1;
        id > 1 ? (id = '[' + id + ']') : (id = '');
        xpath = '/' + element.tagName.toLowerCase() + id + xpath;
    }
    return xpath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, for generating dynamic xpath using java and selenium:
I hope it helps you to some extent :)

```
public static String generateXPATH(WebElement childElement, String current) 
{
    String childTag = childElement.getTagName();
    if(childTag.equals("html")) 
    {
        return "/html[1]"+current;
    }
    WebElement parentElement = childElement.findElement(By.xpath("..")); 
    List<WebElement> childrenElements = parentElement.findElements(By.xpath("*"));
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<childrenElements.size(); i++) 
    {
        WebElement childrenElement = childrenElements.get(i);
        String childrenElementTag = childrenElement.getTagName();
        if(childTag.equals(childrenElementTag)) 
        {
            count++;
        }
        if(childElement.equals(childrenElement))
        {
            return generateXPATH(parentElement, "/"+childTag+"["+count + "]"+current);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```